# Constructor ClassRoll(String f) assignment help, I need to identify why I cannot display the roll

Tags: java, arrays, string, class, constructor

So, basically I have an assignment that requires for me to Write a java program to help maintain a class roll. The program must contain four classes: Student, Exams, ClassRoll and Assignment4(Main).
I have developed all the classes but the ClassRoll constructor it s not performing correctly. When I run the program I am prompted with the file name option, once i enter the file name I see null then the options to modify and / or display the list, but when I enter a command, it does not work, it gives me an error.
The Output should be

```
     Expected input/output:
     Assuming that the file data.txt contains:

     COP2210

     John Doe          50 60 70
     Marco Boyle       50 60 73
     Eric Munzon      45 100 90
     Marry Able       95 100 100
     Jack Smith      100 100 100
     Elizabeth Gomez 100 100 100

     The following is a sample input output run:

     What is the name of input file: data.txt

     Enter one of the following commands

     a or add to add a student in the class roll
     sa or average to sort the students based on their average
     sn or names to sort the students based on their last names
     r or remove to remove a student from the class roll
     s or save to save the list of students back to the datafile
```

Here are my classes;

```
     public class Student {
     private String fName = "";
     private String lName = "";
     private Exam scores;


     public Student(String f, String l){
        fName=f;
        lName=l;
        scores = new Exam();

     }

     public void setScore1(int score) {
        scores.setScore1(score);
     }

     public void setScore2(int score) {
        scores.setScore2(score);
     }

     public void setScore3(int score) {
        scores.setScore3(score);
     }

     public String toString() {
     return lName + "\t" + fName + "\t" +
        scores.toString();
     }

     public double getAverage() {
        return (scores.getScore1() + scores.getScore2() +         
        scores.getScore3())/3.0;
     }

     public boolean equals(String f, String l) {
        return f.equals(fName) && l.equals(lName);
     }

     public int compareTo(Student s){
        if (lName.compareTo(s.lName) > 0)
         return 1;
        else if (lName.compareTo(s.lName) < 0)
         return -1;
        else if (fName.compareTo(s.fName) > 0)
         return 1;
        else if (fName.compareTo(s.fName) < 0)
         return -1;
        else return 0;
     }}
```

```
     public class Exam {

     private int score1;
     private int score2;
     private int score3;

     public Exam(){
        score1=0;
        score2=0;
        score3=0;   
     }

     public void setScore1(int score) {
        score1=score;
     }

     public int getScore1() {
        return score1;
     }

     public void setScore2(int score) {
        score2=score;
     }

     public int getScore2() {
        return score2;
     }

     public void setScore3(int score) {
        score3=score;
     }

     public int getScore3() {
        return score3;
     }

     public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(score1) + "\t"  
           +Integer.toString(score2)
           + "\t" + Integer.toString(score3) + "\t";
     }}
```

```
     public class ClassRoll {

     ArrayList students = new ArrayList();
     String title;
     String fileName;



     public  ClassRoll(String f) throws IOException {

     Scanner fileScan, lineScan;
     String line;
     fileName = f;
     fileScan = new Scanner(new File(f));
     title = fileScan.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Title =" + title);

     while (fileScan.hasNext()) {
        line = fileScan.nextLine();
        lineScan = new Scanner(line);
        lineScan.useDelimiter("\t");
        String lastName = lineScan.next();
        String firstName = lineScan.next();
        Student s = new Student(firstName, lastName);
        s.setScore1(lineScan.nextInt());
        s.setScore2(lineScan.nextInt());
        s.setScore3(lineScan.nextInt());
        students.add(s);
        //display(students);
        ClassRoll c = new ClassRoll();
        c.display();
     }
     }


     void display() {

        DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t" + title);

        double classAverage = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
          Student s = (Student) students.get(i);
          System.out.print(s.toString());
          System.out.println("\t" + fmt.format(s.getAverage()));
          classAverage = classAverage + s.getAverage();
        }
        System.out.println("\t\t\t" + fmt.format(classAverage /      
           students.size()));
        }

        public void insert() {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("First Name -> ");
        String firstName = input.next();
        System.out.print("Last Name -> ");
        String lastName = input.next();
        System.out.print("Score 1 -> ");
        int score1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Score 2 -> ");
        int score2 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Score 3 -> ");
        int score3 = input.nextInt();
        Student s = new Student(firstName, lastName);
        s.setScore1(score1);
        s.setScore2(score2);
        s.setScore3(score3);
        students.add(s);
        }

        private int search(String f, String l) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < students.size()) {
        Student s = (Student) students.get(i);
        if (s.equals(f, l)) {
            return i;
        } else {
          i++;
        }
        }
         return -1;
        }

        public Student find() {

         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("First Name -> ");
         String firstName = input.next();
         System.out.print("Last Name -> ");
         String lastName = input.next();

         int i = search(firstName, lastName);

         if (i >= 0) {
            return (Student) students.get(i);
         } else {
            return null;
         }}


         public void delete() {

           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.print("First Name -> ");
           String firstName = input.next();
           System.out.print("Last Name -> ");
    String lastName = input.next();

    int i = search(firstName, lastName);

    if (i >= 0) {
        students.remove(i);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Student not found");
    }
    }

    public void sortLastNames() {
       for (int i = 0; i < students.size() - 1; i++) {
       for (int j = i + 1; j < students.size(); j++) {
            Student s1 = (Student) students.get(i);
            Student s2 = (Student) students.get(j);
            if (s1.compareTo(s2) > 0) {
                students.set(i, s2);
                students.set(j, s1);
            }
        }
      }}

      public void sortAverage() {
        for (int i = 0; i < students.size() - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < students.size(); j++) {
            Student s1 = (Student) students.get(i);
            Student s2 = (Student) students.get(j);
            if (s1.getAverage() < s2.getAverage()) {
                students.set(i, s2);
                students.set(j, s1);
            }
        }}}

    public void save() throws IOException {
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fileName);
    out.println(title);
    for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
        Student s = (Student) students.get(i);
        out.println(s.toString());
    }
    out.close();

     }}
```

```
   public class Assignment4bis {


   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {       

    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the name of the input file ->");
    String fileName=input.next();

    ClassRoll c = new ClassRoll();
    c.display();

    prompt();
    System.out.print("Enter a command --> ");
    String ans=input.next();


  while (!(ans.equalsIgnoreCase("q") || ans.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")))       
  {
  if(!(ans.equalsIgnoreCase("i") ||ans.equalsIgnoreCase("insert") ||
       ans.equalsIgnoreCase("a") || ans.equalsIgnoreCase("average") ||
       ans.equalsIgnoreCase("n") || ans.equalsIgnoreCase("names") ||
       ans.equalsIgnoreCase("r") || ans.equalsIgnoreCase("remove") ||
       ans.equalsIgnoreCase("f") || ans.equalsIgnoreCase("find") ||
       ans.equalsIgnoreCase("d") || ans.equalsIgnoreCase("display")))
       System.out.println("Bad Command");
   else
       switch (ans.charAt(0))
        {
            case 'i':   c.insert();
                        break;
            case 'a':   c.sortAverage();
                        c.display();
                        break;
            case 'n':   c.sortLastNames();
                        c.display();
                        break;
            case 'r':   c.delete();
                        c.display();
                        break;
            case 'f':   Student s=c.find();
                        if (s == null)
                            System.out.println("Student not found");
                        else System.out.println(s.toString());
                        break;
            case 'd':   c.display();

                        break;
        }
        prompt();
        System.out.print("Enter a command --> ");
        ans=input.next();
    }
    c.save();
    System.out.println("Thank you for using this program");

    }

    public static void prompt(){
    System.out.println("Enter one of the following commands");
    System.out.println("i or insert to insert a student in the class  
       roll");
    System.out.println("a or average to sort the students based on 
       their average");
    System.out.println("n or names to sort the students based on their 
       last names");
    System.out.println("r or remove to remove a student from the class  
       roll");
    System.out.println("f or find to find a student in the class 
       roll");
    System.out.println("d or display to display the class roll");
    System.out.println("q or quit to exit the program");
    }}
```

```
    Errors that I m still getting...

    run:
    Enter the name of the input file ->data.txt
    Title =COP2210
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
     at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
     at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
     at assignment4bis.ClassRoll.<init>(ClassRoll.java:40)
     at assignment4bis.Assignment4bis.main(Assignment4bis.java:28)
    Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ClassRoll "constructor" is a "pseudo-constructor":

```
public class ClassRoll {
     ArrayList students = new ArrayList();
     String title;
     String fileName;

     public void ClassRoll(String f) throws IOException {
```

Constructors have no return type, so get rid of the `void`:

```
public class ClassRoll {
     ArrayList students = new ArrayList();
     String title;
     String fileName;

     public ClassRoll(String f) throws IOException {
```

As a bit of side recommendations:

- You look to be mixing user interface with one of your "model" or logical classes, ClassRoll, something you probably shouldn't do. I'd keep all user interface code, including use of a Scanner and File I/O separate from ClassRoll, which likely should just have code to create the collection, to allow other classes to add or remove from the collection, and to allow other classes to query the collection.
- Take care to learn and follow Java code formatting rules. You've got some deviations from the standard, including have your class declaration lines indented the same as the method body and variable declaration lines, bunching up of end braces,... This makes your code hard for other Java coders to read and understand.

Comment: @mariaandreaerramouspe: "giving me errors" tells us little. Always read the error messages critically, focus on the lines that the error messages point to, and if still stuck, post your latest code and your error messages, indicating which lines cause them, as an edit to your question.

Comment: @mariaandreaerramouspe: This is a completely different problem and may require a new question. Your code to parse the file is not correct, and is trying to parse non-numeric data as numeric. As the exception message is telling you: `ClassRoll.java:40`, look critically at line 40 of ClassRoll.java, whichever line that is.

Comment: cannot identify my errors...ughhhhh i ve been at it for days now, i don t know what else to try.....

Comment: Again, your new problem is unrelated to the original problem for this question, so again post a new well-formulated question on this site.  But not here with this old question, again a completely new question.

Comment: @mariaandreaerramouspe: Give up if you wish, but what is so hard about asking a new question? You just click the new question button and post your latest code specific to the new problem and a detailed problem statement. But if you can't do this or don't want to, that's OK.

Comment: idont know what or how else to ask, ive edited my question and tried to go back andlook for the errors i got, again i wish i could identify those myself, but i cannot as of yet... i am not asking for code i have actually developed the entire program but i just dont know what else to do

Comment: @mariaandreaerramouspe: what to do: formulate a new question for this new problem. Don't edit this question -- ask a new question. Press [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and post. That's it.

Comment: hahaha will do, thanks, advise a new topic for me please...hahaha